# Cannot open Microsoft Dynamics NAV service links in a browser

Tags: soap, microsoft-dynamics, navision

I need to integrate Microsoft Dynamics NAV web services on the website. They provided me with a list of services URLs to access in a browser to see the XML structure. When I open, I see Sign In window, I enter username and password but window still prompts me to enter details. My IP is whitelisted, server IP as well and I send SOAP requests from server's specific IP. But no results.

I asked them and they told that they can see the XML in a browser. For me, I can imagine why I cannot get any results because if in browser the authentication is not working, it will not work for the server requests too.

I tried to turn off antivirus, restart the internet, tried with other PC,etc...but nothing, same result - looped sign in window 
(see the attachment).

[image]

Any ideas please? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is also not working for me in Chrome. It works in IE/Edge with the credential manager from windows and in Firefox with basic credentials.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: I'm not using chrome to lookup the list:-)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the [Boomerang SOAP and REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/boomerang-soap-rest-clien/eipdnjedkpcnlmmdfdkgfpljanehloah) for Chrome.
I use Web Services only with IE/Edge.

In the background of your Screenshot the page says that you are not authorized (HTTP 401). Is your user also a user in Dynamics NAV/Business Central?

Comment: is there a difference which browser you use to see Web Services? are there any issues with Chrome? The person who gave me URLs of services, is using Chrome and no issues with it. It doesn't work for others to whom they are giving access.